# sequential search implementation

Tags: java, class, search, methods

Hey guys I am trying to write a class and one of my methods in my class is suppose to search an array looking for the item whose product item is given by me 3rd parameter. I have 2 issues.

1. I don't know how to declare an array inside a class with out specifying size
2. I know I must use sequential search to search array but I don't know how to implement the code for this in the class.

```html
public static int ProductSearch(GroceryItems[] product, int numProducts, int productNumber)
```

Comment: numProducts is not required, as from the array length the required search operation can be performed

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking for any attribute match of POJO class.

in this example if attr will not found then -1 will be required.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        GroceryItems[] GroceryItems = new GroceryItems[]{new GroceryItems(5), new GroceryItems(22), new GroceryItems(45), new GroceryItems(95)};
        int ProductSearch = ProductSearch(GroceryItems, 5, 67);
        System.out.println(ProductSearch);
    }

    public static int ProductSearch(GroceryItems[] product, int numProducts, int productNumber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
            if (product[i].productNumber == productNumber) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static class GroceryItems {

        int productNumber;

        public GroceryItems() {
        }

        public GroceryItems(int productNumber) {
            this.productNumber = productNumber;
        }
    }
```

Comment: here i have considered the productNumber into bean/class and comparing with productNumber attr of bean/class for one by one seq search.

Comment: I agree, use a bean and implement equals method. +1

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not create array without setting size. There is some Collection, for example ArrayList what does the job behind the scene (create a larger size of array and copy to it)
2. ArrayList also has search method, so you can use it and do not need to deal with searching algorithm. Only thing you should understand is the equals method in this sample:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProdSearch {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<GroceryItems> prods = new ArrayList<GroceryItems>();

    GroceryItems p1 = new GroceryItems();
    p1.setProductNumber(1);
    prods.add(p1);

    GroceryItems p2 = new GroceryItems();
    p2.setProductNumber(4);
    prods.add(p2);

    GroceryItems p3 = new GroceryItems();
    p3.setProductNumber(1);

    boolean res = productContains(prods, 123, p3);
    if (res) {
        System.out.println("Contains..");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No such an element..");
    }
}

public static boolean productContains(List<GroceryItems> product, GroceryItems productSearch) {
    return product.contains(productSearch);
}
```

}

class GroceryItems {
    int productNumber;

```
public int getProductNumber() {
    return productNumber;
}

public void setProductNumber(int productNumber) {
    this.productNumber = productNumber;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + productNumber;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    GroceryItems other = (GroceryItems) obj;
    if (productNumber != other.productNumber)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the @override?

Comment: @override annotation is generated by Eclipse, it is a hint when you override (redefine) a method of superclass. If there is nothing to override, the code will not compile, so it will help to check the correct method decoration, but it is not necessary.

Comment: I am instructed for class prod to contain the search algorithm or in this case it is in main, that is where im confused I just do not know how much should go in my class definition its becoming very stressful I have to use the method listed in the original problem. I do not have to use sequential search I could use your array list however could you edit the code including my method public static int productSearch(GroceryItems[] products, int numProducts, int productNumber)

Comment: Ok, I did it, I hope you need that. ;) Good luck!

Comment: Your code uses arraylist where as in the questions specified to use array.

Answer (score 0):

- method name beginning with the first letter lowercase
- GroceryItems[] -> products
- productNumber is also an attribute of GroceryItem

public static int productSearch(GroceryItems[] products, int numProducts, int productNumber) {

```
    boolean found = false;
    int i = 0;

    if (products == null || 
        products.length != numProducts || 
        numProducts < 1))
        return -1;

    while (!found && i < numProduct) {
        if (products[i].productNumber == productNumber)
            found = true;
        else i++;
    }

    if (!found)
        i = -1;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Yes, except when is -1.